# Can I completely exclude a pane title?

Tags: 7, panels

I'd like to apply several panes without title to a panel (in Drupal 7).

I can select *Override title* and leave the input field blank, but this still leaves the wrapping HTML.

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h2 class="panel-title"></h2>
</div>
```

Can I completely exclude a title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learnt adding `<none>` to the title field does this.